# Javascript Date without Time Zone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I make a web-service call and the data is returned as JavaScript, which has date in it.

```
    "d": [{
        "__type": "ServiceValues",
……………………..
        "DateOfServiceStart": new Date(1453093200000),
        "DateOfServiceEnd": new Date(1463457600000),
        "CreatedDateTime": new Date(1453161233940),
        "UpdatedDateTime": new Date(1453329075943),
...........
    },
```

However when using the same to display the value as received from the server, JS does not allows the same.

The server date is “2016-01-18 18:53:53.940” for the CreatedDateTime value received.

I have looked for several solutions around the same and also moment.js. But none is working.

I want the date to be displayed as it is received from the server.

Here is the snipped for the same, where none of the options is returning date as it was received from the server.

```
<html><head><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script></head><Body>
    <div id="localDate"> </div>
    <BR><BR>
    <div id="time"> </div>
    <script>
        var localFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY';

        //SERVER DATE : “2016-01-18 18:53:53.940”

        var serverDate = new Date(1453161233940);       

        var _helsenkiOffset = 2*60*60000;//maybe 3 [h*60*60000 = ms]
        var _userOffset = serverDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60000; // [min*60000 = ms]
        var _helsenkiTime = new Date(serverDate.getTime()+_helsenkiOffset+_userOffset);

        var m = moment(serverDate).format(localFormat);

        var mom = moment(1453161233940).format(localFormat);

        document.getElementById("localDate").innerHTML += _helsenkiTime + '<BR>';   

        document.getElementById("localDate").innerHTML += serverDate.toUTCString() + '<BR>';    

        document.getElementById("localDate").innerHTML += m + '<BR>';

        document.getElementById("localDate").innerHTML +=  mom + '<BR>';    

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: *"...is returned as JSON object, which has date in it."* That's not JSON. `new Date(...)` is JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: thanks, I have edited it.

Comment: didn't get your question.

Comment: I need to display the date received form the Database Server, as it is without any JS modification due to timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The server date is “2016-01-18 18:53:53.940” for the CreatedDateTime value received.

Either that's incorrect, or that's the value in **local** time for that server, and your server appears to be in GMT-05:00. The time value in question (1453161233940) is actually Mon Jan 18 2016 23:53:53 UTC. So I see two possibilities: Your server is in the eastern U.S. or Canada, since those are in the Eastern Standard timezone (-05:00) in January, or somewhere along the way something has adjusted that time value by five hours incorrectly.

You can get that UTC value (Mon Jan 18 2016 23:53:53 GMT+0000) from your `Date` object using the various `getUTCXyz` methods. Then, if you want to adjust it in some way for display, you can do so with the various `setXyz` or `setUTCXyz` methods (or, of course, their `moment` equivalents).

It's important to remember that -05:00 isn't *always* Eastern time. A server on Eastern time will be at -05:00 most of the year (Eastern Standard Time), but -04:00 during "daylight saving time" (Eastern Daylight Time).

The moral is that when storing dates, you need to think carefully about timezones and store the date in the way that best suits your application. One way is to store dates in UTC always, since you can convert from UTC to any other timezone easily when you want to render. Another way is to always store the date **and** its timezone, which is what SQL Server's `datetimeoffset` type does.

Comment: Let me try to explain it better, the Server Date received is the value retrieved from the Database, as are other values, so Web Server location doesn't matters.

The value is correct cause if you convert the "Server date" get the valueOf the same. The value returned is the same.

`var validateDate = new Date('2016-01-18 18:53:53.940');
document.getElementById("localDate").innerHTML += validateDate.valueOf() + '<BR>';`

Comment: @RakeshSingh: Again, 1453161233940 is Mon Jan 18 2016 23:53:53 UTC. Your example is using an undocumented string format with `new Date` ([here's the only documented one](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format)), and so the browser can give you any value it wants. It's probably parsing as "local time" which will be offset from UTC (by 5 hours, if you're in India or Pakistan). The TZ of the web server may matter, or the TZ of the DB server may matter. Fundamentally, you need to understand what new Date(1453161233940) means and work from there.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't think the TZ of DB Server or Web Server would matter here as the value returned is what is stored in DB.

The thing is I don't want the UTC or Local Time zone based time. I want the time as returned by the Web Service and as it is stored in Database.

Short of using string to return the time, as of now there seems to be no alternative.

Comment: @RakeshSingh: *What* is stored in the DB? Many DBs have a DATE or DATETIME type, which is absolutely affected by the TZ. If you're actually storing the *number* 1453161233940 in the DB, then it's down to you to give that number meaning. Is it the standard milliseconds-since-the-Epoch UTC? Or is it some custom value (which would be a Really Bad Idea)? What you seem to be saying is that it's a custom value, in which 1453161233940 somehow magically means something five ours different from what it would mean in any kind of standard way.

Comment: Thanks for repeating again and again, it finally got into my Head that 1453161233940 is Mon Jan 18 2016 23:53:53 UTC

And since the date stored in DB was actually EST (although no mention of it in the value itself)

The following moment.js worked to get the time as stored on server.

`moment(1453161233940).utcOffset('-0500').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: @RakeshSingh: I'm really glad that was helpful!

Comment: IST is +0530 by the way.

Comment: @torazaburo: Ah, good point. Well, the sign was wrong anyway, so I figured it was indeed Central Daylight.

Comment: @RakeshSingh - Don't use hardcoded time zone offsets.  You'll find your assumptions are wrong when time zones changes their offsets for daylight saving time and other reasons.

Comment: @RakeshSingh: Re Matt's advice above (which is good): For instance, I didn't look closely at the *date* portion of what you gave (sorry), but it's definitely not Central Daylight time as I said at first -- because it's in January. GMT-0500 in January is Eastern Standard Time. You might want to look at the dates your server is currently recording, as they may well be GMT-04:00 (Eastern Daylight time) instead of GMT-05:00.

Comment: I also figured that out, therefore using moment timezone as below:
moment(1453161233940).tz('America/New_York').format(localFormat)